# Что такое каркас в "песне танкистов"?

Tags: значение

(Русский не мой родной язык).

В песне "На поле танки грохотали" есть такие слова:

> Нас извлекут из-под обломков, 
> Поднимут на руки каркас, 
> И залпы башенных орудий 
> В последний путь проводят нас.

Что такое *каркас*?

Я нашел
"Каркас — внутренняя несущая конструкция, состоящая из сочетания линейных элементов. Каркас призван выдерживать нагрузки, обеспечивать прочность и устойчивость объекта",
но в этом случае это определенно что-то другое.

Answer (score 8):

Текст этой песни разбирался в Интернете уже не раз.
Вот фрагмент [одного из таких разборов](https://masterok.livejournal.com/6261848.html):

> каркасом назывались специальные носилки на ножках, при помощи которых в танк загружали боекомплект. Было у каркаса и второе, более печальное предназначение — служить для переноски тел погибших танкистов, которым отдавали воинские почести.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132771/discussion-on-answer-by-ivan-olshansky------).

Answer (score 3):

Нижегородский областной архив в 2015 году опубликовал [письма с фронта](https://www.archive-nnov.ru/?id=8881), в одном из них, датированном 7 июня 1944 г., куплет передан так:

> И вынут нас из-под обломков,
> **Наденут на плечи каркас**.
> Зальются птицы в небе звоном,
> Проводят до могилы нас.

Это, наверно, самое раннее письменное свидетельство, и оно не очень вяжется с гипотезой о "носилках на ножках для боекомплекта".

Есть ещё вариация этого куплета, в котором каркас надевают на руки:

> И вынут нас из-под обломков,
> **Наденут на руки каркас**.
> Взлетают в небо ястребочки,
> Проводят нас в последний раз.

И есть вариант про десантников, где каркас тоже одевают, видимо, при жизни:

> Нас посадят на машину,
> **Оденут на плечи каркас**,
> Взовьются в небе самолеты,
> И ястребы проводят нас.

Я не знаю, что за каркас можно было *надеть* на плечи или руки. Может быть, хоть и маловероятно, это аналог выражений *надеть деревянный макинтош*, *натянуть на плечи деревянный бушлат*.

UPD:

Дальнейшие поиски привели меня к [фрагменту](http://militera.lib.ru/prose/russian/grossman/04.html) из книги Гроссмана, [«Жизнь и судьба»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0), написанной в 1950—1959 годах:

> И вынут нас из-под машины,
> **Поднявши на руки каркас**,
> Взовьются в небо ястребочки,
> В последний путь проводят нас.

Здесь речь идёт о лётчиках, и всё выглядит более-менее логично.

И ещё один вариант про лётчиков есть в повести Евгения Воробьева, «Незабудка», датированном 1962 годом:

> И вынут нас из-под кабины,
> **Поднявши на руки каркас**,
> Взовьются в небо «ястребочки»,
> В последний путь проводят нас.

Вероятнее всего, *каркас* перекочивал из этого варианта в "танкисткий", хотя там он совершенно нелогичен. А потом этот вариант попал в роман В. А. Курочкина «На войне как на войне», по которому была экранизация, и уже в таком виде песня обрела широкую популярность.

Comment: Спасибо. Я вижу, что проблема сложнее, чем я думал.

Comment: @Przemysław Scherwentke Вот линк на одно из обсуждений в Интернете. Там один из участников ссылается на объяснения своего деда-танкиста, который говорил, что это именно носилки для снарядов.Текст песни мог искажаться, когда его повторяли нетанкисты. Обратите внимание, что во всех вариантах, приведенных Ильей, отсутствует упоминание башенных орудий. Люди не понимали, что такое "каркас", но оставляли это слово, поскольку оно необходимо для рифмования со строчкой "в последний путь проводят нас. 
  http://otvet.mail.ru/question/211521434

Comment: _нас извлекут из-под обломков_ is much more likely to be about a crashed plane than a burned tank

Comment: @Quassnoi до меня только сейчас дошёл ваш аргумент! Действительно, проблема ведь не только в том, что у современных на тот момент танков не было каркаса, а если бы и был - его нельзя было бы поднять на руки. Но, как вы верно подметили, извлекать останки танкиста **из-под** обломков - танка лишено смысла. Излекали **из** танка (если ещё было, что извлекать).

Answer (score 1):

Каркас — это элемент кабины самолета. Когда самолёт разбавается, чтобы добраться до останков пилота поднимают каркас самолета, то что осталось от кабины.
Думаю, перекочевало это в песню о танкистах совершенно машинально, создав путаницу и непонимание.

«Кабина похожа на длинную металлическую овальную трубу. Ее основу составляет металлический каркас из дюралевых шпангоутов и стрингеров. Снаружи каркас обшит также дюралем, внутренние же стенки обшиты тонкой шерстяной тканью, которая скрадывает звук и делает кабину похожей на маленькую, длинную, хотя и тесную, но уютную комнатку с оконцами и двумя люками»

https://studfile.net/preview/9909325/page:5/

Здесь подробное описание кабины пилота (фонарь кабины пилота), с открывающимся люком.

Comment: Зачем тело поднимать на руки?

Comment: @artptr - На похоронах тело к могиле несут на руках.

Comment: @YellowSky но речь-то не про похороны, а про извлечение из танка. Когда героя чествуют, его тоже на руки поднять могут, но не хоронить же его несут и явно не отдают предпочтение телу по сравнению с душой.

Comment: @artptr - А что, «проводить в последний путь» – это не значит «хоронить»? Что, песня не про гибель танкистов?

Comment: @YellowSky конечно про гибель, но на похоронах несут не само тело, а гроб с телом. Или, как предлагают выше, носилки с телом.

Comment: Если быть реалистичным, в условиях войны хоронили как придётся (если вообще хоронили). В гробу - редко. Иногда в снарядных ящиках, чаще - завернув в плащ-палатку, в общей могиле. А могли и просто в ближайщую воронку покидать и чуть присыпать. Про залпЫ башенных орудИЙ - вообще что-то непонятное. Ну может полковника, или большая братская могила. Хотя я не знаю, практиковался ли вообще салют из танковых пушек? Обычно артиллерийские залпы дают.